# How do I use pyodbc.connect() with authorization=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

Trying to access Azure SQL through a python function in VS code, with Authentication set to Active Directory Integrated. Using pyodbc to connect.

Works fine when run locally but get an error after deploying to Azure. Also works fine if I use SQL login but I want to use Active Directory Integrated. I have already set myself as an AD admin.

What I am trying:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:khawajaserver1.database.windows.net,1433;Database=KhawajaDB1;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated")
```

Error I get:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error code 0x57 (87) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 308, in _handle__invocation_request
```

Comment: Try to use  SSMS to connect to your Azure database with "Active Directory Integrated" autherization, show us the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I know Active Directory Password as authentication type works.

```
db_list = [TEST_DB1, TEST_DB2]
sql_conn = None
for db in db_list:
    try:
        conn_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' \
                      'SERVER=' + <db_url> + \
                      ';DATABASE=' + <db_name> + \
                      ';UID=' + <db_username> + \
                      ';PWD=' + <db_password> + \
                      ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
        print conn_string
        sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:::", e
    print 'Cannot connect to DB' + str(sys.exc_info()[0])
    return None
sql_conn.cursor().execute(<some SQL Query>)
sql_conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

when using the **ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server**, the following works when you are using some form of Managed Identity to connect to an Azure SQL Instance;

```
conn_str = 'Driver={};SERVER=tcp:{},1433;DATABASE=CustomerProfiling;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi;'.format("{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}", os.environ["SQL_SERVER"])
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

The key is to use the **ActiveDirectoryMsi** Authentication attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
# Connection to SQL Server using AADIntegrated

import pyodbc 

server = 'data1.database.windows.net' 
database = 'MyTestDB' 
authentication = 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
kpi_server_connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Authentication='+authentication+';TrustServerCertificate='+ 'no')

query_string = '''
    select top 10 * from [SomeTable] 
    '''
df = pd.read_sql(query_string, kpi_server_connection)
df
```